# Почему не выполняется Ajax запрос?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, почему не выполняется ajax запрос?Или я что-то не понимаю. Но смысл всего этого в том, что мне нужно разместить ссылку на странице, нажав которую откроется окошко с содержимым вот этой страницы https://site.ru/adler.php

```js
// обработка нажатия (click) на ссылку, с классом btn_ajax
$('.btn_ajax').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // отмена события по умолчанияю 
    
    // метод Ajax POST
    $.post(
        "https://site.ru/adler.php", // ссылка на php файл, который будет обрабатывать запрос
    {}, // объект запроса, если ничего не надо передать, то оставляем пустым
    onAjaxSuccess // вызов функции обработчика ответа
    );

    // функция, которая обрабатывает ответ. Ответ представляет из себя объекта data
    function onAjaxSuccess(data)
    {
        // Здесь мы получаем данные, отправленные сервером и выводим их на экран.
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn_ajax">CLick me</a>
```

Comment: Может быть, потому что нельзя делать кроссдоменные аякс запросы без разрешения владельцев сервиса?

Comment: Вы про какой сервис? Я на сайте aviareysi.ru внизу на фотографии адлер разместил кнопку Динамика цен и сделал запрос как в коде, но он не работает

Comment: А почему "открыть окошко" надо именно js скриптом? Классическими методами html нельзя действовать?

Comment: Тогда надо было без домена урл писать.

Comment: @vp_arth пробовал, все равно не работает

Comment: @Tachkin Помогите с идеей, дайте пример, ну хоть что-нибудь)

Comment: @Arcadiy,  ошибка `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at aviareysi.ru/:549` с этим же никак не связана?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы слишком рано навешиваете событие обработки клика. jQuery ещё не загрузился.
Переместите скрипт ниже, после того, как подключаете `jquery`
И уберите атрибут `async`, чтобы дождаться загрузки скрипта:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Вообще, в таких случаях, всегда смотрите консоль(F12) на наличие ошибок.
В вашем случае она выглядит так:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: О сейчас заработало, но высвечивается в виде кода, а надо чтоб в виде графика

Comment: Ну, в окошке алерта вы график не отрисуете. Задавайте новый вопрос)

Comment: Возможно вас устроит простой `window.open('https://aviareysi.ru/adler.php')`

Comment: А как его правильно сформулировать? Я про новый вопрос

Comment: `Как в jquery нарисовать модальное окно с highcharts?`

Comment: Так оно же у меня нарисовано.

Comment: Вы же видите в алерт кучу лишнего DOM? Вам нужно аякс получить только данные для диаграммы и отрисовать его тут на странице в модальном окне. Либо открыть новое окно браузера с полной страницей, как я указал выше.

Comment: задал новый вопрос, этот принял